# Pentaho spoon is not starting

Tags: java, pentaho-spoon

I'm just trying to open the GUI interface, but it is not opening and without any reason, any error message.
Any Idea?

```java
C:\software\data-integration>Spoon.bat
DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin\javaw.exe

C:\software\data-integration>start "Spoon" "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin\javaw.exe"  "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx1024m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-DKETTLE_HOME=C:\software\data-integration\" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-8.0.0.0-28.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, what I did was add a variable called PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS and in the value field put -Xms1024m. It worked for me.

[Pentaho Spoon Bat Will not launch v2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PH6mWe3YVCQ)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the hidden directory C:\Users\.kettle, delete the file called `db-cache-xxx`. Do not touch to the `kettle.property`, `repository.xml`, `shared.xml` if you did define some connections or custom setup.
2. Remove unused plugins. Copy the folder named `plugins` elsewhere. Try to see if spoon launch quicker. Then copy back the plugins (=folders), you need one by one.
3. Be patient. Sometimes your OS needs quite a bit of time to find the required memory space. Windows did not think it was important to give you feedback of what was happening in the background.

Comment: Thanks all,
In the command line I just put this command:
##
java -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-8.0.0.0-28.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64
###
And it opened the application again...... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set `PENTAHO_JAVA _HOME = C:\Pentaho\Java`
AND
Set a system variable called `JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre`

Mine is setup the same way and works perfectly fine. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **"C:\Program Files\Java"** path copy your JRE folder that is present there.
2. Open you **"C:\Pentaho\data-integration"** folder and paste the JRE folder that is copied
3. Rename the JRE folder that is in "data-integration" folder which is of the format
   **"jre_version"** eg: **"jre1.8.0_241"**, to **"jre"**. Now you will be having a folder with the
   name "jre" in your "data-integration" folder.
4. Now you can try running spoon.bat as "Run as administator", with in less than a minute
   your Pentaho UI will open.

This will work even if your having java is installed with the path being set and pentaho is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho PDI (8.2) did not start.

I copied then the jre-xxx folder to c:\pdi, the base base of my PDI installation and renamed the new folder to jre. Therefore the java base folder is now c:\pdi\jre.

I had then to set the system env. variables JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME to path c:\pdi\jre. can be done in windows by control panel -> system & security -> system -> extended system settings -> system environments -> edit/add the mentioned system variables -> set the java base path.
i used the jre-install file: jre-8u301-windows-x64.exe

then i changed the PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS entry in spoon.bat.

instead of the default line:

if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx6096m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

i used that one:

if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx1024m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

additional: to start spoon.bat as admin can help, if there are permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. For me setting the KETTLE_HOME variable caused the problem. When I changed the variable from "D:\config" to "D:\config" it worked again...

Answer (score 0):

I had to use 64 bit version of Java, and set the system variable **PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME** to the 64 bit installation folder location: **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1_version**. For some reason using 32 bit version of Java did not work on my system. Pentaho version 9.3.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed spoon.bat on windows for PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS variable value.Modified
`"-Xmx2048m"`  to `"-Xmx1024m"` then it worked.

```
"%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" **"-Xmx1024m"** "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

fyi
https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/198116-PDI-6-does-not-start/

Answer (score 0):

The approach I had taken was to download the set-pentaho-env.bat and place this in the data-integration folder (link - https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/assemblies/core/static/src/main/resources-filtered/set-pentaho-env.bat)
Also set three environment variable
PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME
JRE_HOME
This worked for me